# Reactjs styled-components return error ',' expected

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

[Reactjs] When I try to use styled-components to customize atlaskit button css return error ',' expected
[image]
[image]

I tried to find a solution but no one seems to have the same error as me

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, upload your actual code, not pictures of it when posting questions. Secondly, check the docs and examples for styled components library. You need to use **backticks** to wrap the CSS, not regular quotes or double quotes. i.e.

```
const b = styled(Button)`margin-top: 5px;`;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's why. I already fixed it